# how to check if a form is valid programmatically using jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with a couple of buttons and I'm using jQuery Validation Plugin from http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/. I just want to know if there is any way I can check if the form is considered in valid state by jquery validation plugin from anywhere in my javascript code.

Comment: For those wishing to use HTML5 and vanilla JS (no jQuery): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470622/how-can-i-check-the-validity-of-an-html5-form-that-does-not-contain-a-submit-but

Comment: ```document.forms['formID'].reportValidity()``` returns true if all the form elements validity is true. (For non jQuery users)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Use [`.valid()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) from the jQuery Validation plugin:

```
$("#form_id").valid();
```

> Checks whether the selected form is valid or whether all selected
>   elements are valid. validate() needs to be called on the form before
>   checking it using this method.

Where the form with `id='form_id'` is a form that has already had `.validate()` called on it.

Comment: Thank you, I was already doing something like: 

$j("#myform label.error").each( function(i,e) {
                    if($j(e).css('display') != 'none') {
                        existErrors = true ;
                    }
                });

:S Thanks

Comment: There's actually no need to have .validate() run on the form first. You can simply do if (form.valid()) {} and that will work, where 'form' is the form element you're targeting.

Comment: awesome.. i was stuck with fileupload and finally found a way through this post... waah Taaj :)

Comment: The `$("#form_id").valid()` method always returns true :-( regardless of the validity of the form. It only triggers the validity check, but returns true, even when the form is invalid.

Comment: TypeError: $("#myForm").valid() is not a function.

Comment: had the same issue with @artgrohe

Comment: If you are receiving a `TypeError valid() not a function` add the plugin to your file since its a plugin not included in jquery library eg. `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 35):

**2015 answer:** we have this out of the box on modern browsers, just use the [HTML5 CheckValidity API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity) from jQuery. I've also made a [jquery-html5-validity module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-html5-validity) to do this:

```
npm install jquery-html5-validity
```

Then:

```
var $ = require('jquery')
require("jquery-html5-validity")($);
```

then you can run:

```
$('.some-class').isValid()

true
```

Comment: can we call it on whole form not on each element?

Comment: Great! just what I was looking for

Comment: I prefer this rather than the `valid` function as it doesn't call the `validate` function and validate your form.

Comment: @parisssss Made a module to do it on multiple selections as requested.

Answer (score 35):

@mikemaccana answer is useful.

And I also used https://github.com/ryanseddon/H5F. Found on http://microjs.com. It's some kind of polyfill and you can use it as follows (jQuery is used in example):

```
if ( $('form')[0].checkValidity() ) {
    // the form is valid
}
```

Comment: this one is better since it doesn't trigger form validation

Comment: Work with pattern attribute. Thanks.

Comment: `checkValidity` is native JS for checking validity of a `HTMLFormElement` and Forms I believe. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation#constraint_validation_process)

Answer (score 7):

For a group of inputs you can use an improved version based in @mikemaccana's answer

```
$.fn.isValid = function(){
    var validate = true;
    this.each(function(){
        if(this.checkValidity()==false){
            validate = false;
        }
    });
};
```

now you can use this to verify if the form is valid:

```
if(!$(".form-control").isValid){
    return;
}
```

You could use the same technique to get all the error messages:

```
$.fn.getVelidationMessage = function(){
    var message = "";
    var name = "";
    this.each(function(){
        if(this.checkValidity()==false){
            name = ($( "label[for=" + this.id + "] ").html() || this.placeholder || this.name || this.id);
            message = message + name +":"+ (this.validationMessage || 'Invalid value.')+"\n<br>";
        }
    })
    return message;
}
```

Comment: I've made a jQuery plugin to do the .each() for you.

Answer (score 6):

valid() method.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid

Answer (score 4):

iContribute: It's never too late for a right answer.

```
var form = $("form#myForm");
if($('form#myForm > :input[required]:visible').val() != ""){
  form.submit();
}else{
  console.log("Required field missing.");
}
```

This way the basic HTML5 validation for 'required' fields takes place without interfering with the standard submit using the form's 'name' values.

Comment: Note, that `:input`and `:visible` selectors are jQuery extensions and not part of CSS.  See details in [docs](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Comment: A form can also be invalid because of pattern matching and not only because missing required fields

Answer (score 2):

For Magento, you check validation of form by something like below.

You can try this:

```
require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my-button-name').click(function () { // The button type should be "button" and not submit
            if ($('#form-name').valid()) {
                alert("Validation pass");
                return false;
            }else{
                alert("Validation failed");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 1):

In case you're validating before submitting the form:

```
$(function(){
    $('.needs-validation').on('submit', function(event){
        if(!event.target.checkValidity()){
            // Form didn't pass validation
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).addClass('was-validated');
        }
    })
})
```

You can't use `$('form')[0].checkValidity()` with multiple forms in the view.