# How can I check the validity of an HTML5 form that does not contain a submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have the following code example that works in browsers that check when they see the HTML5 "required" on an input like the email here:

```
<form id='myForm'>
    <div>
    <label>Email:
      <input name=email type=email required title="enter your email">
    </label>
    <input type=submit>
    </div>
</form>​
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6jhE/) for the above.

However in my application I use a **button outside of my form** and the following code attached to the click event of that button:

```
if (!$form.valid || $form.valid()) {
    $submitBt
        .disableBt();
    $modal
        .removeBlockMessages()
        .blockMessage('Contacting Server, please wait ... ', {
            type: 'loading'
        });
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $form.serializeArray()
    })
        .done(onDone)
        .fail(onFail);
}
```

I have two questions here:

- What does the following code do: (!$form.valid || $form.valid())
- How can I check my form validity using the new HTML5 checks?

Comment: Where did you get the example from?  $form is an object, and it isn't defined anywhere, so there's a piece of this puzzle that's missing.

Comment: Declare that $form = $('#myForm)

Comment: Thanks for adding the $form = $('#myForm). I did miss that out.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Assuming that you have set the form element to an object called `$form`, then `if (!$form.valid || $form.valid())` is clever syntax that means "if `$form` doesn't have a  method called `valid`, or if `valid()` returns true". Typically you will have installed and initialized the jQuery Validation plugin by then, but this prevents the form from becoming disabled if the validation plugin is not loaded.

You can do a similar test using the HTML5 method `checkValidity`, looking something like this:

```
if (!$form.checkValidity || $form.checkValidity()) {
  /* submit the form */
}
```

**EDIT**: checkValidity is [a function from the HTML5 forms spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-checkvalidity). As of February 2016 CanIUse.com reports that [over 95% of browsers support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation).

Comment: Is checkValidity a jQuery function? The reason I am asking this is because I looked it up and saw $('#profileform')[0].checkValidity()  Based on that post I read I am wondering if I should have [0] included.

Comment: @Anne I edited the post with a couple extra links. Basically, `checkValidity` is an HTML5 function and not part of jQuery. Regarding the `[0]`, the jQuery `$` function returns lists of objects when you pass it a string, so in order to get back to a single object (like your form) you need to specify an index. Look up `.get(index)` in the jQuery documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the links. My code looks like this: var $form = $modal.find('#main-form');  When I tried the line of code you had it just passed over the line without doing anything even though I specify an ID in my selector. So should I change this to var $form = $modal.find('#main-form')[0]; ?

Comment: Basically, yes. Both `$('query')` and `object.find('query')` return an object confusingly called a "jQuery", and you need to use `.get(0)` or `get(0)` in order to get back to a single item that as a checkValidity method. It's like the difference between opening a bookshelf and opening a book--doing it with a collection just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I updated my fiddle but still can't get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/E6jhE/1/  Can you see anything that is wrong. Sorry to be asking so many questions and thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Fixed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E6jhE/5/). For one, checkValidity() may or may not show the user their invalid fields, but will return true if and only if all the fields are valid. For another, `<div id="#foo">` is always incorrect; never put a hash tag within an ID attribute. In jQuery and CSS, you use the hash mark to say "the word coming up next is an ID, not a class or tag name". Finally, I fixed the framework in the left bar--make sure you're working with jQuery and not Moo. Hope this helps!

Comment: In the HTMLFormElement api there is also the method [reportValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) which returns false if a form element is invalid **and** fire `invalid` events for each non-valid elements. **But** unfortunately this is not compatible with any IE version: [90% browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=reportValidity).

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, you may use a "form" attribute on an element to explicitly associate it with a Form element regardless of where it is positioned in the page structure:
http://developers.whatwg.org/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attr-fae-form

In compliant browsers, you ought to be able to put your input[type=submit][form=id] element anywhere and still have it properly trigger the validation and submission process.

I tend to put code that is supposed to intercept the submission process in the form's "submit" event handler, that way it is triggered by users hitting the Enter key as well as any input[type=submit] buttons I have.