# check for character length before saving via ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm using pattern to check for character length before saving using form tag with

```
pattern=".{6,}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password must be 6 atleast characters')"
```

but that doesnt work when I'm saving using ajax/jquery. it directly saves the text without checking for character length/ pattern

this is my form and ajax/jquery (it's inside a modal)

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
                          <div style="display:inline-block">
                               <input type="password" id="password" class="my-2 form-control"  
placeholder="Type password" name="" pattern=".{6,}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password must be 
6 atleast characters')" required><br>
                               <input type="password" id="confirm_password" class="mt-2 form-control" 
onclick="repass()" placeholder="Retype password" name="" pattern=".{6,}" 
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Password must be 6 atleast characters')" required><br>
                               <span id='message'></span>
                          </div>
                     </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_password" disabled>Change Password</button>
                 <a href="admin_logout.php">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</button>
                 </a>
                </div>
```

```
<script>
    function repass(){

         $('#password, #confirm_password').on('keyup keydown', function () {
         if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirm_password').val()) {
         $('#message').html(' ').css('color', 'red');
         $('#submit_password').attr("disabled", false);
    } else{
         $('#submit_password').attr("disabled", true);
         $('#message').html('Password does not match').css('color', 'red');
         }
         // if (($('#password').val()) == null) {
         //      $('#message').html(' ').css('color', 'red');
         //      $('#submit_password').attr("disabled", true);
         //
         // }
    });
}
    </script>
     <script>
        $("#submit_password").click(function(e) {
            // e.preventDefault();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {password:password},
                url: 'change_pass.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    // alert(data);
                    swal( {
                       title: "SUCCESS!", text: "Password changed!", icon: "success", timer: 1800, button: false,
                   }
                   );
                   $('#change_pass').modal('hide');
                }
            });
        });
     </script>
```

Comment: Use `$("form").on("submit",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`  instead of clicking a submit button - the preventDefault is MANDATORY if you do not want to submit the form as well as performing the ajax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check the validity of an HTML5 form that does not contain a submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470622/how-can-i-check-the-validity-of-an-html5-form-that-does-not-contain-a-submit-but) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658937/how-to-check-if-a-form-is-valid-programmatically-using-jquery-validation-plugin

Comment: @freedomn-m unfortunately no. I've seen that before asking the question but it does not answer it, or maybe it does in some parts but I'm not proficient enough to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the validation rules don't appear is because your inputs are not contained within a `form`, and you do not submit that form. If you correct that, your code will work.

Also note that you can improve the HTML by removing the inline event handlers and attaching them unobtrusively. Try this:

```js
$('#password, confirm_password').on('invalid', function(e) {
  this.setCustomValidity(e.target.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Password must be 6 atleast characters' : '');
});

$('#password, #confirm_password').on('keyup keydown', function() {
  if ($('#password').val() === $('#confirm_password').val()) {
    $('#message').html(' ');
    $('#submit_password').attr("disabled", false);
  } else {
    $('#submit_password').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#message').html('Password does not match');
  }
});

$("#yourForm").on('submit', function(e) {
  var password = $('#password').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      password: password
    },
    url: 'change_pass.php',
    success: function(data) {
      // success actions...
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#message {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="yourForm">
  <div style="text-align:center;">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
      <input type="password" id="password" class="my-2 form-control" placeholder="Type password" name="" pattern=".{6,}" required><br>
      <input type="password" id="confirm_password" class="mt-2 form-control" placeholder="Retype password" name="" pattern=".{6,}" required><br>
      <span id='message'></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_password" disabled>Change Password</button>
    <a href="admin_logout.php">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: yes, this solved it. I didn't know I can remove the inline event handlers and use javascript for that. thank you.

Comment: You forgot `$("#yourForm").on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault()` as I commented

Answer (score 0):

```
var password = $('#password').val();

if(password.lenth < 6){
 console.log("Length must be 6 character long");
 return false;
}
```

Comment: it still proceeds to saving the text