# Do after form submission

Tags: jquery, forms

I have HTML:

```
<div id="my_form">
   <form action="https://example.com" method="POST" target="_blank">
      <input type="email" required>
      <input type="submit" class="submit_button" value="Submit">
   </form>
</div>
```

When user clicks on submit, new window opens and stuff happens. Works fine.

Now, I want to hide a div *after* the form is *successfully* submitted, so I tried:

```
$(".submit_button").click(function() {
    $("#my_form").hide();
});
```

Works fine, **but** it closes the div regardless if the form was actually submitted. For example, if user leaves the email input empty, and clicks submit. The form is not submitted, but the div gets hidden.

How do I hide the div when the form is successfully triggered?

Comment: Maybe `onsubmit` :D EDIT: So I guess I just answered my own question. Good night my dear coding players! lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check the validity of an HTML5 form that does not contain a submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470622/how-can-i-check-the-validity-of-an-html5-form-that-does-not-contain-a-submit-but)

Answer (score 1):

Use submit() event instead of click() event.

```
$("#my_form").submit(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    return false;
});
```