# How to check for Form completion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable/enable navigation based on whether the current form has all it's required fields filled correctly or not. Is there a property or some JQuery function to call which will tell me if the form is complete or not?

Comment: this question is very broad - form validation is always a very customized thing to be done, can you provide a code example?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I would say use any validation plugin and u r all set. jquery.validate.js is the most famous one,

Answer (score 2):

Also worth looking at jquery validation plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 1):

To answer this as broadly as possible with regards to today's standards, you might want to look into [HTML5 form validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/).

Answer (score 0):

got it thanks.

The valid() function is what I was looking for. I had been playing with JQuery Validation plugin but didn't see this key function.

[how to check if a form is valid programmatically using jQuery Validation Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658937/how-to-check-if-a-form-is-valid-programatically-using-jquery-validation-plugin)